# Compare two RSA encrypted strings which uses different encoding

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, rsa, padding

I have a string "test_string", which is encrypted using RSA algorithm using two different encodings as shown in the below C# code. I want to check if the encrypted value in both the cases are the same, since I am using the same key in both cases. But due to RSA padding, the encrypted value changes every time even if I am using the same key and the same data "test_string" and same encoding. So, is there any way I can make sure that the encrypted value is same/different by avoid the padding? Any other recommendations are welcome.

```
        string encryptedUTF16;
        string encryptedUTF8;

        RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
        RSAParameters rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

        using (var rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa1.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            byte[] bytesEncrytedKeyUTF16 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test_string".ToCharArray());

            byte[] encrytedKeyUTF16 = rsa1.Encrypt(bytesEncrytedKeyUTF16, true);
            encryptedUTF16 = Convert.ToBase64String(encrytedKeyUTF16);
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedUTF16);
        }

        using (var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa2.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            byte[] bytesEncrytedKeyUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test_string".ToCharArray());
            byte[] encrytedKeyUTF8 = rsa2.Encrypt(bytesEncrytedKeyUTF8, true);
            encryptedUTF8 = Convert.ToBase64String(encrytedKeyUTF8);
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedUTF8);
        }
```

I tried using OpenSSl and BouncyCastle as well. But ran into technical issues running them.

Comment: Title and body of the post ask very different questions... (I think it is quite obvious that string as UTF16 vs. UTF8 would have different bytes and hence different encrypted bytes - not really sure why title asks to compare such encrypted sequences).

Comment: That’s not really the goal of RSA. Most crypto APIs don’t make it easy to do “textbook RSA” (no padding) since that leads to [security vulnerabilities](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1449) in most applications. You may consider signing (rather than encrypting) the value.  Hashing or hashing a key plus the data may work, too. Depends on what you are aiming for.

Comment: If you want to compare the UTF-8 versus UTF-16 encodings of a string then just do that. There's no point involving RSA in that comparison.

Comment: Finally, as alluded to by @AlexeiLevenkov, RSA is a *permutation* of the integers mod N, where N is the RSA modulus. Different inputs (as long as they are encoded into different integers mod N) are guaranteed to have different outputs even without any randomized padding. If it wasn't a permutation then you couldn't have unique decryption, which would be a fatal flaw for an encryption system.

Comment: There is such a thing as [deterministic encryption schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_encryption) and they have their place. However, one has to remember that for an **asymmetric** encryption scheme such as RSA we assume that the attacker has both the public key and the algorithm, so that means that an attacker can simply try to encrypt messages until the right ciphertext is found. I don't see how this could be used for solving any problem in the question above.